# C "pass by pointer" value not updated when expected

Tags: c, gcc, embedded, i2c, mplab

I have a function where the `data` value is updated by a library call and returned via pointer.  Note that in the body of the function, I print the de-referenced value of `data` following the call to `I2C_Transfer()`

```
static bool read_reg(uint8_t reg, uint8_t *data) {
    bool success = I2C_Transfer(appData.drvI2CHandle,
                                APP_OV2640_SENSOR_I2C_ADDR,
                                (void *)&reg, sizeof(reg),
                                (void *)data, sizeof(uint8_t));
    printf("after I2C_Transfer(%02x), *data = 0x%02x\r\n", reg, *data);
    return success;
}
```

The call to `read_reg()` looks like this:

```
uint8_t vid = 0x55;  // pre-initialize vid for debugging
printf("before read_reg(), vid = 0x%02x\r\n", vid);
read_reg(0x0a, &vid);
printf("after read_reg(), vid = 0x%02x\r\n", vid);
```

When I run it, I see the following:

```
before read_reg(), vid = 0x55          // <= as expected
after I2C_Transfer(0a), *data = 0x55   // <= expected *data = 0x26
after read_reg(), vid = 0x26           // <= as expected
```

Note that vid = 0x26 is the expected result.

**The question**: Why does `printf("after I2C_Transfer()")` print 0x55 rather than 0x26?  It is almost as if the compiler doesn't know that I2C_Transfer() updated *data by reference and decided to print the cached value.

## Update III: it's a vendor library bug

Despite the fact that the SPI_Transfer() function is documented as a blocking function, there's strong evidence (which I have yet to prove) that the function is returning before the last data byte is received.  And since interrupts are still enabled, the interrupt routine updates the data register after the function has returned.

So: nothing to see here.  Move along...

I move to close this entry.

## Update II: stubbing `I2C_Transfer()`

When I stub `I2C_Transfer()` with the following, it works as expected:

```
static bool I2X_TransferStub(const DRV_HANDLE handle, uint16_t address,
                         void *const writeBuffer, const size_t writeSize,
                         void *const readBuffer, const size_t readSize) {
    uint8_t *rx_buf = (void *const)readBuffer;
    *rx_buf = 0x26;
    return true;
}
```

And the output looks like this:

```
I2C_TransferStub(0x0a) on entry, data = 55
I2C_TransferStub(0x0a) => 26, success = 1
```

So what is surprising to me is that in a bare-metal environment (no OS) that the value of `*data` is somehow updated *after* the call to `I2C_Transfer()` returns.

### Update: source code for `I2C_Transfer`

Commenters have requested the source code for I2C_Transfer.  Its real name is `DRV_I2C_WriteReadTransfer()`, shown here.  It's worth pointing out that this is a synchronous function: it doesn't return until a value is produced.

```
bool DRV_I2C_WriteReadTransfer(const DRV_HANDLE handle, uint16_t address,
                               void *const writeBuffer, const size_t writeSize,
                               void *const readBuffer, const size_t readSize) {
    return lDRV_I2C_WriteReadTransfer(handle, address, writeBuffer, writeSize,
                                      readBuffer, readSize,
                                      DRV_I2C_TRANSFER_OBJ_FLAG_WR_RD);
}

static bool lDRV_I2C_WriteReadTransfer (
    const DRV_HANDLE handle,
    uint16_t address,
    void* const writeBuffer,
    const size_t writeSize,
    void* const readBuffer,
    const size_t readSize,
    DRV_I2C_TRANSFER_OBJ_FLAGS transferFlags
)
{
    DRV_I2C_CLIENT_OBJ* clientObj = (DRV_I2C_CLIENT_OBJ *)NULL;
    DRV_I2C_OBJ* hDriver = (DRV_I2C_OBJ*)NULL;
    bool isSuccess = false;
    bool isReqAccepted = false;

    /* Validate the driver handle */
    clientObj = lDRV_I2C_DriverHandleValidate(handle);

    if (clientObj == NULL)
    {
        return isSuccess;
    }

    if (transferFlags == DRV_I2C_TRANSFER_OBJ_FLAG_RD)
    {
        if((readSize == 0U) || (readBuffer == NULL))
        {
            return isSuccess;
        }
    }
    else if ((transferFlags == DRV_I2C_TRANSFER_OBJ_FLAG_WR) || (transferFlags == DRV_I2C_TRANSFER_OBJ_FLAG_WR_FRCD))
    {
        if((writeSize == 0U) || (writeBuffer == NULL))
        {
            return isSuccess;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if((writeSize == 0U) || (writeBuffer == NULL) || (readSize == 0U) || (readBuffer == NULL))
        {
            return isSuccess;
        }
    }

    hDriver = clientObj->hDriver;


    /* Block other threads from accessing the PLIB */
    if (OSAL_MUTEX_Lock(&hDriver->transferMutex, OSAL_WAIT_FOREVER ) == OSAL_RESULT_SUCCESS)
    {
        /* Error is cleared for every new transfer */
        clientObj->errors = DRV_I2C_ERROR_NONE;

        /* Errors if any, will be saved in the activeClient in the driver callback */
        hDriver->activeClient = (uintptr_t)clientObj;

        /* Check if the transfer setup for this client is different than the current transfer setup */
        if (hDriver->currentTransferSetup.clockSpeed != clientObj->transferSetup.clockSpeed)
        {
            /* Set the new transfer setup */
            (void) hDriver->i2cPlib->transferSetup(&clientObj->transferSetup, 0);

            hDriver->currentTransferSetup.clockSpeed = clientObj->transferSetup.clockSpeed;
        }

        switch(transferFlags)
        {
            case DRV_I2C_TRANSFER_OBJ_FLAG_RD:
                if (hDriver->i2cPlib->read_t(address, readBuffer, readSize) == true)
                {
                    isReqAccepted = true;
                }
                break;

            case DRV_I2C_TRANSFER_OBJ_FLAG_WR:
                if (hDriver->i2cPlib->write_t(address, writeBuffer, writeSize) == true)
                {
                    isReqAccepted = true;
                }
                break;


            case DRV_I2C_TRANSFER_OBJ_FLAG_WR_RD:
                if (hDriver->i2cPlib->writeRead(address, writeBuffer, writeSize, readBuffer, readSize) == true)
                {
                    isReqAccepted = true;
                }
                break;

            default:
                     /* Nothing to do */
                break;
        }

        if (isReqAccepted == true)
        {
            /* Wait till transfer completes. This semaphore is released from ISR */
            if (OSAL_SEM_Pend( &hDriver->transferDone, OSAL_WAIT_FOREVER ) == OSAL_RESULT_SUCCESS)
            {
                if (hDriver->transferStatus == DRV_I2C_TRANSFER_STATUS_COMPLETE)
                {
                    isSuccess = true;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            /* Update error into the client object*/
            clientObj->errors = hDriver->i2cPlib->errorGet();

            if(clientObj->errors == DRV_I2C_ERROR_NONE)
            {
                hDriver->transferStatus = DRV_I2C_TRANSFER_STATUS_COMPLETE;
            }
            else
            {
                hDriver->transferStatus = DRV_I2C_TRANSFER_STATUS_ERROR;
            }
        }

        /* Release the mutex to allow other threads to access the PLIB */
        (void) OSAL_MUTEX_Unlock(&hDriver->transferMutex);
    }

    return isSuccess;
}
```

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: That's kind of impossible to say if we do not know what `I2C_Transfer()` is supposed to do.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I'd love to oblige, but I2C_Transfer() is a call to an MPLAB library function for a specific microcontroller.  Not sure that would be useful.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Why do you need to know the internals of I2C_Transfer()?  Does not the declaration tell the compiler all it needs to know?

Comment: If I2C_Transfer() is setting up a async operation that will be completed after some hardware delay, then the C code may be printing the old value because the new value has not yet been updated. Caching effects may be in play, so you may want to attempt volatile to force read from memory.

Comment: I see your point, but we need to know what the function is supposed to do. Maybe link to some documentation then.

Comment: @jhx: I2C_Transfer() is explicitly synchronous and won't return until the value is computed.   I'll post the sources...

Comment: @fearless_fool: “… but I2C_Transfer() is a call to an MPLAB library function for a specific microcontroller”: So, to make a [mre], you define it with a stub routine in a separate source file as `bool I2C_Transfer(const DRV_HANDLE handle, uint16_t address, void* const writeBuffer, const size_t writeSize, void* const readBuffer, const size_t readSize) { * (uint8_t *) readBuffer = 0x26; return true; }`. If the problem vanishes then, you know there is something about `I2C_Transfer` that is causing the problem beyond putting a value in `*data` (such as some memory corruption/buffer overrun)…

Comment: … If it does not vanish, then you continue reducing the rest of the program until you either find the problem or have a [mre] for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I certainly could, but the question remains: given how C works, how can the value of *data change between returning from `I2C_Transfer()` and returning from `read_reg()`?  What the heck, I'll try it...

Comment: @EricPostpischil MRE added, and the problem vanishes.  But that doesn't answer my question :) : how could I2C_Transfer() be written in a way to cause the value of `*data` to be changed after it returns?

Comment: Re “given how C works, how can…”: If a program does what it is supposed to do, there is no bug. Therefore, debugging, by definition, is a search for an incorrect supposition. So you cannot take it as a given that C works. You question all assumptions. To do that, you perform tests. Swap out one implementation for a routine for another. Isolate parts. Examine intermediate values. Something may be breaking how C works…

Comment: … If I were working on this, I would tell the compiler to generate assembly for `read_reg` and for the routine that calls it, so I could see exactly where the bits for printing `*data` were coming from. However, there is still no [mre] in the question, as a [mre] would require a `main` routine and definitions of all the types and identifiers used in the code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256134/discussion-between-fearless-fool-and-eric-postpischil).

Comment: Also, `static bool I2X_TransferStub…` is not the stub I suggested. I wrote to put a definition of `I2X_Transfer` in a separately compiled file. That is important, to prevent the compiler from seeing the definition when it compiles `read_reg`. Maybe you left `read_reg` calling `I2C_Transfer` and made a replacement definition of `I2C_Transfer` in another file that calls `I2X_TransferStub`, but we cannot see that because that code is not in the question. So we cannot reproduce it. So it is not a [mre].

Comment: You are describing your understanding of that function. You do not show the implementation of the underlying "writeRead" function, which may or may not do what you expect it to in terms of interaction with OSAL_SEM_Pend.

Comment: Note that you never need to cast a pointer _to_ `void*`.  That is kind of the point of `void*` and where you have `(void *)data, sizeof(uint8_t)` you would do better to use `data, sizeof(*data)` so that no assumptions about the type of `data` are required.

Comment: You would have to step through in your debugger at assembly level, or otherwise inspect the code at the assembly level to determine what is happening here. Are you building with or without compiler optimisation? Shouldn't matter, but if there is a bug in the compiler, it is more likely to be in the optimiser.